# How to find the shortest path of inputted list of nodes in nodes-only graph in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, path

I am pretty new to the topic of graphs so maybe this is a known problem, and I just haven't found an appropriate name. So to explain. Imagine we have a graph with *n* nodes - stored as an adjacency list. This is an undirected weighted graph, that is placed on a cartesian plane (so you can get the distance between each node). But you only have the vertices, not edges, like in this picture:
[image]

Now I input a list of nodes (random ordered), for instance `[n2,n7,n1]` and the algorithm should find the  route how to connect these nodes with a minimal distance and then return ordered array - for instance `[n1, n2, n7]`

To me this doesn't seem the same as pathfinding algorithms since you are inputting a list of nodes, any idea how to approach this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the traveling salesman problem. You can find a lot of literature on it, but you can start with the Wikipedia page.

To adapt it to your problem, you can create a graph with all your nodes and add one arbitrary node with equal distance to all other nodes, which will work as your starting point of your traveling salesman.

Solving techniques for a traveling salesman problem depend on the size of the problem, how close you want to be to the optimal solution, how fast you want your algorithm to be, *etc*.

Comment: Isn't TSP that you have to end in the starting node and therefore create a cycle?

Comment: @SamuelV. Variants exist